# .NET Core not showing up in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 after install core

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, aws-lambda

I just installed dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.1.exe to get .Net Core 1.04 on my machine. 
I'm u\Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, but ".Net Core" doesn't appear in the list of frameworks available.  I want to change to make my software work with AWS Lambda. 
I have closed/re-opened Visual Studio, but not rebooted.

This leads to my bigger question here: [Code re-use with .NET 4.0 DLL (that uses Nuget packages) with .NET CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758443/code-re-use-with-net-4-0-dll-that-uses-nuget-packages-with-net-core)

[image]

[image]

Comment: .NET Core projects use the new .csproj format which is not supported by Visual Studio 2015. You can only use the older `project.json` format, which is only available through a tooling preview support and does not support .NET Core 2. You should consider upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 if you can, or you will be limited to the command line experience.

Comment: Yes, they are supported, that's not my issue.  I have to add a new "core project" or new "AWS lambda project" to get Core.  But, I want to switch existing non-core code to core code.

Comment: My point is that .NET Core uses *different project files*. So you cannot change an existing project into .NET Core without also migrating the project file to the new format.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like maybe you cannot change an existing project. 
After installing the AWS Toolkit, and the Core Toolkit I was able to add an AWS Lambda Project.  Then looks like soon I will be able to "publish" it to AWS (as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymn6WGCSjE4)

I was hoping to just take some code I had already written and convert it, rather than creating an entirely new project.